# How to find the Dual space

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

If i consider the following space $$L^p_{\theta}=\{u:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}~\text{ mesurable}, \int_{\Omega} ||x|^{\theta} u(x)|^p dx<\infty\}$$ where $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is an open bounded set, and $\theta>\frac{N}{2}$

What is the dual space of $L^{p}_{\theta}$ ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your $L^p_\theta$ is just $L^p(\mu_\theta)$, where $\mu_\theta$ is the measure
$\|x\|^\theta \; dx$ restricted to $\Omega$, so  (if $1 \le p < \infty$) its dual is identified with $L^q(\mu_\theta) = L^q_\theta$ where $1/p + 1/q = 1$ by the pairing
$\langle f, g\rangle = \int_\Omega f(x) g(x) \|x\|^\theta \; dx$.

Comment: i don't understand $L^p_{\theta}=L^p (\mu_{\theta})$ can you explain me more ?

Comment: For any measure $\mu$ on a space $X$ with $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$, $L^p(\mu)$ is the Banach space of $\Sigma$-measurable functions (up to equivalence $\mu$-almost everywhere) $f$ such that
$\int_X |f|^p\; d\mu < \infty$, with norm $\|f\|_p = \left(\int_X |f|^p\; d\mu \right)^{1/p}$.